# Two column layout does not work properly

Tags: css, xhtml, html, css-float

I am trying to make a HTML page using two column layout.

I have a version in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/eFMpJ/35/

I am unable to set a top margin for the the inner container.Though I have given a top-margin for the innerContainer its not been reflected in the page.

The reason I am using an inner container for containing the left-sidebar and innerContainer is that in the actual page I have two more divs side by side in the inner-container.I do not prefer to use three column layout for that reason.

Comment: Please always place the relevant code within your question.  Links are great but if they disappear they question is no longer useful to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with margin collapsing.  You can prevent the margins from collapsing by using a border or padding.  There's a good explanation here:  http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

http://jsfiddle.net/eFMpJ/46/

```
#outerContainer
{
   background-color:#FFF000;
   margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;

   border-top: 1px solid black;
   // or padding-top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem fixed . So due to margin collapsing the the greater of two values of margins of divs placed side by side vertically is taken. Since this is a case of parent and child case the larger of the margin is applied. Just take a look at this.  http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/eFMpJ/61/                      In this case I just applied a top-margin of 150px on innerContainer. But what happened is the larger of two values (150px , from 0 and 150px)is selected and applied to parent(outerContainer). Is my explanation of the observation correct. Just confirming my understanding.

Comment: Yup, and putting a border or padding on the parent item will stop the collapsing and cause the margins to be treated independently.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the closing div is missing for the opening .
Then I added padding-top of 10px in outerContainer.

```
#outerContainer
{
   background-color:#FFF000;
   margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
   padding-top: 10px;

}
```

I think this will solve your problem.
Please let me know what is the result.

Comment: hey did you just copied the answer from @James

Comment: not at all, may be @James and me working simultaneously in the issue.